# Why can't I install these expo navigation dependencies?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to run the commands listed here:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

I installed "navigation" itself correctly

But when I try the following command:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

I get the following error:

```
Installing 5 SDK 36.0.0 compatible native modules using npm
> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I've installed them before with no problem with other projects, so I don't know why this could be happening

Comment: are you using expo or react native?

Comment: I'm using both of them

Comment: no , imean how did you create your project?>

Comment: I used expo. The command "expo init [projectname]"

Comment: hi klippy did you just solved the issue as i am also facing the same issue